# Command to compare and sort 2 files with different word counts

Tags: perl, unix, compare

Hello I have 2 files with jumbled up content. File1 might have some 100 strings one below the other and file 2 has 200 for instance.

Something like

```
File1 a-->001 b-->002 c-->003 d-->004 e-->005
File2 b-->001 c-->003 d-->009 e-->005 z-->026 y--> 025 0-->15 p-->16 a--> 001
```

I want it to arrange like this so that I could see the corresponding differences

```
File1 a-->001 b-->002 c-->003 d-->004 e-->005
File2 a-->001 b-->001 c-->003 d-->009 e-->005 z-->026 y--> 025 0-->15 p-->16
```

I tried the sort command sort file1 and sort file2 and diff -y -suppress-common-lines file1 file2 >diff.txt but this one messes up when I have say 10 words starting with a. So it will show all 10 a's followed by b.. So is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I've done some work on the layout, but I'm not at all sure I understand the file formats.  Are you dealing with 1-line files?  Or multi-line files?  Can you show 10 lines of each of File1 and File2 (and the desired output for the given input data)?  Indent the lines by 4 spaces (in the edit box, select the material to indent and hit the **`{}`** button above).

Comment: @Rancho, sure, you can use Perl for your task. are you familiar with this language?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

if ($#ARGV != 1)
{
    print "\nUsage: test.pl File1 File2\n\n";
    exit();
}

my $file1 = getFile($ARGV[0]);
my $file2 = getFile($ARGV[1]);

my $r = {};
while (my ($k, $v) = each %$file1)
{
    if (!exists($file2->{$k}))
    {
        $r->{$k} = "[$v, undef]";
    }
    elsif ($v ne $file2->{$k})
    {
        $r->{$k} = "[$v, $file2->{$k}]";
    }
    delete $file2->{$k};
}
while (my ($k, $v) = each %$file2)
{
    $r->{$k} = "[undef, $v]";
}

foreach (sort keys %$r)
{
    print "$_ -> $r->{$_}\n";
}

sub getFile($)
{
    my $f;
    return open($f, shift()) ? return { (join('', <$f>) =~ /[\s\n\r^](\w+)\s*-+>\s*(\d+)/g) } : {};
}
```